# Problem while giving strings in os module

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

```
import os

def compute(path, fileExt):
    if os.path.exists(path):          # checks if the path entered by the user exists
        print("The path exists")

        for foldername, subfolder, filename in os.walk(path):
           for file in filename:
               if file.endswith(fileExt):
                   print(os.path.join(foldername, subfolder, *file))
    else:
        print("The path does not exist !")
```

This program is about printing the full path of all the files in the folder mentioned by the user ending by the extension also mentioned by the user.
When I run the program i get a error on line 10 stating that : *TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'list'*. I checked the variable type of *file* by using *type(file)* and it return *str*.
Where wrong ??

Comment: `subfolder` is a list here, not file. You may want to check your logic here. Try printing only subfolders in the `if` loop and then modify the code based on what you want the output to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should double check the [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) documentation and look closely at the error message you are getting. Your error message indicates you are trying to combine a list and a string. You have verified that `file` is a string, but what about `foldername` and `subfolder`.

`os.walk()` returns three things, the current directory file name, a list of all subdirectories of the current directory, and a list of all files in the current directory. This tells us that `foldername` is also a string but `subfolder` is actually a list of strings which causes the error message you are seeing.

Additionally, all of the `files` returned by `os.walk()` are contained within the `root` directory, not within the subdirectories. Therefore to print the path of the file, you want to join the file name to the `root` file path.

Just focusing on the `os.walk()` portion of your question, the following will print the full path of all files with the given file extension:

```
import os
for foldername, subfolder, files in os.walk(top, topdown=False):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(fileExt):
            print(os.path.join(foldername, file))
```